# How to use basejoin from urllib in Python 3

Tags: python

I am trying to import a third party library from Python 2 to Python 3. Here is the code:

```
#
# python2.3 urllib.basejoin does not remove current directory ./
# from path and this causes problems on subsequent basejoins.
#
basejoin = urllib.basejoin
if sys.version_info[0:2] < (2, 4, 0, 'final', 0)[0:2]:
    #basejoin = lambda base,url: urllib.basejoin(base,url.lstrip('./'))
    token = './'
    def basejoin(base, url): 
        if url.startswith(token) is True:
            return urllib.basejoin(base,url[2:])
        return urllib.basejoin(base,url)
```

I am getting this error `AttributeError: module 'urllib' has no attribute 'basejoin'`

Comment: Maybe try using urllib.parse.urljoin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me on Python 3.5:

```
from urllib3.packages.six.moves.urllib.parse import urljoin
basejoin = urljoin
```